# XmlParseException for a picture on a button

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, image

I would like to insert a picture une a button, and, when i run my application, i have a XmlParseException.

I don't know why :(

```
<Button Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="15,2,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="41">
    <Button.Background>
         <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/search.png" Stretch="None"></ImageBrush>
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

Anyone have an idea please ?

Comment: Which line gives the exception?

Comment: The <ImageBrush ImageSource....>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your Visual Studio project contains an `Images` folder which in turn contains the image file `search.png`. Moreover the [Build Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c6xyb66.aspx) of the image file must be set to `Resource`.

Answer (score 0):

You must check if your image has set `Build Action` property to `Resource`:

[image]

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni No, in my code is "/" before `Images/search.png`.

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni Your path is ok, but the Build Action `Resource` is important.